# What would be the resource configuration of Nexus 9 - 2014?

Tags: android, configuration, android-resources

I was wondering what the resource configuration of Nexus 9 would be? Would it be sw720dp like the Nexus 10?

[GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_nexus_9-5823.php) says it's 1536 x 2048 pixels, 8.9 inches (~281 ppi pixel density), so I'm guessing it would be xhdpi and the width in dp would therefore be 768, so should fall under sw720dp. However, I'm not sure and would like to confirm with better informed people out there.

Also, is it a device which looks like it'd be used in landscape more than portrait? Currently for sw720dp, the default orientation for one of the screens in my app is landscape and was wondering if it would be best for Nexus 9 also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Getting Your Apps Ready for Nexus 6 and Nexus 9](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) post on the Android Developers Blog, the Nexus 9 has:

> (...) a screen size of 2048 x 1536 pixels (288 ppi), **which translates
>   to 1024 x 768 dip**. This is a 4:3 aspect ratio, which is unique
>   compared to earlier tablets. The Nexus 9 falls into the xhdpi density
>   bucket, and you should already have assets in the drawable-xhdpi
>   folder.

So, yes `sw720dp` would seem to be correct.

About orientations, it says:

> It’s very important that you don’t lock your app to a single
>   orientation. **The Nexus 9’s natural orientation is portrait mode, while
>   it’s used in landscape mode with the keyboard.**

Answer (score 1):

According to this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html

the Nexus 9 should be in the AVD device definitions (API21 5.0). However I am not seeing it. I do see Nexus 5 (not sure which API that came in).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. Nexus 9 Screen Information

[image: Nexus 9 Screen Information]